# DXF entities not showing on import into QGIS

Tags: qgis, dxf

I regularly get sent DWG files containing Ordnance Survey base mapping (variously with & without additional layers). I usually re-scale & reposition these in Draftsight, or just run a conversion in Teigha Converter. So far so good.

I have received a DWG with OS mapping & a site boundary. If I convert that to DXF(I usually have success with 2010 ASCII), all I get in QGIS is the site boundary polyline & a load of points.

If I open in a CAD program (Draftsight,QCAD etc) , the DXF that doesn't work in QGIS, I can see the whole drawing.

There is only 1 polyline entity in the import box, so its not that they're all down at 0,0 or something.

I can reproduce this on Linux & Windows, so not related to that.

Any idea where to look?

Comment: Have you looked in the DXF file? There may be some unsupported entities by QGIS.

Comment: I have looked in the DXF - there are the usual OS entities present - I don't know what entities are unsupported by QGIS.  It is a simple  DWG - just the original mapping features & a site boundary.  Not user how these could get changed?

Comment: It's something to do with the DWG - some operations in Draftsight only select the site boundary, which is the only layer in addition to the standard OS mapping layers.  I can't identify why this should be - from the layer manager or elsewhere. The mapping does not appear to be an XREF (I think)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the base mapping layers were in a block (unsupported entity presumably).
I exploded the block & business as usual.